# How to Let Users Insert Number of Iteration

Tags: matlab, loops, iteration

I'm working with k-means on MATLAB. To process the valid cluster, it needs to do a looping until the cluster position doesn't change anymore. So, looping more than 10 iterations is possible. And it may take a long time.

So, I want to let users to set the iteration. Example: user inputs '3' for the iterations, then the iterations will be lasted until 3 iteration. Here is the snippet of iteration process:

```
   while 1,
            d=DistMatrix3(data,c);   % calculate the distance 
            [z,g]=min(d,[],2);      % set the matrix g group

            if g==temp,             % if the iteration doesn't change anymore
                break;              % stop the iteration
            else
                temp=g;             % copy the matrix to the temporary variable
            end
            for i=1:k
                f=find(g==i);
                if f                % calculate the new centroid 
                    c(i,:)=mean(data(find(g==i),:),1);
                end
            end
  end
```

All I know is I have to define a variable to let users input the number of iterations. That variable will be used for the looping/iteration process. I have tried it by deleting `while 1` to `for i=1:iteration`. But it still doesn't work like I want. Anyone know how to do this?

All the answers will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work like [you] want"? Your idea should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close. The reason that `for i=1:iteration` doesn't work is that you are using the variable `i` in an inner loop: `for i=1:k`.  When that inner loop is finished, `i` will have a value of `k`, regardless of what the outer loop was doing. Most compilers would complain about something like this - but by default Matlab doesn't... To solve this, all you need to do is use a unique variable for the outer loop, for example `itNum`:

```
for itNum = 1:iterationCount  % <<<< new line, ensures at most "iterationCount" iterations
  d=DistMatrix3(data,c); % calculate the distance 
  [z,g]=min(d,[],2);     % set the matrix g group

  if g==temp,            % if the iteration doesn't change anymore
    break;               % stop the iteration
  else
    temp=g;              % copy the matrix to the temporary variable
  end

  for i=1:k
    f=find(g==i);
    if f                 % calculate the new centroid 
      c(i,:)=mean(data(find(g==i),:),1);
    end
  end

end                      % end of for itNum... loop
```

As an aside, it is a pet peeve of mine when people use `i` as a variable. Matlab has a built in variable `i` that has the value of `sqrt(-1)`. When you assign a new value to it, it loses that intrinsic value which might just break some other code...

Another point of style/efficiency: your code

```
        for i=1:k
            f=find(g==i);
            if f                % calculate the new centroid 
                c(i,:)=mean(data(find(g==i),:),1);
            end
        end
```

Is usually considered inefficient. If possible, avoid using `find`; if you do use it, make sure you use the result. For example (avoiding `find`):

```
for i=1:k
  if any(g==i)
    % calculate the new centroid 
    c(i,:)=mean(data(g==i,:), 1);
  end
end
```

Or (re-using the result of `find`):

```
for i=1:k
  f = find(g==i)
    if f
      % calculate the new centroid 
      c(i,:)=mean(data(f,:), 1);
  end
end
```

Which of these is more efficient will depend on the size of `g`...